# Run application with privileges without helper

Tags: macos, cocoa, privileges

I'm currently launching an application with privileges by means of a helper, which is fine.
The downside is, at every launch the user is prompted its data.

However, is it possible to assign the application root privileges, with the user's permission to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and you should not do this.
If your application runs with root privileges, and it has a security flaw, then your application might become an entry point for a hacker trying to comprise your user's machine.

You should move to a model where the privileged operations are performed by a helper tool and your main application does not have any special privileges.

The Apple sample code is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/SMJobBless/

Comment: I know I shouldn't do that, I want to know how I could do that, since I'd use it for myself. The point is, I'd like to avoid prompting everytime the user a window asking its data.

Comment: Once your helper tool is installed by SMJobBless, you don't need to call SMJobBless again. Your tool is already installed and privileged. So this will only ask for the password once. See this discussion: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/309298-question-about-smjobbless.html

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't read entirely the Read Me. The only problem is it isn't compatible with Leopard.